# Как именно и в какой момент применяются опции запуска Chrome при использовании его в headless режиме?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, https, facebook-php-webdriver

Суть такова. Есть `Selenium` (standalone) и к нему `chromedriver`. Первый запускается сразу с параметрами, указывающими, где лежит второй, и таким образом второй в итоге доступен без лишних плясок при обращении к первому.

Обращаемся мы к нему через библиотеку `php-webdriver`, написанную ребятами из `Facebook`. Для примера кусок кода:

```
        $chrome_options->addArguments([
            'no-sandbox',
            '--incognito',
            '--disable-application-cache',
            '--disable-async-dns',
            '--dns-prefetch-disable',
            '--ignore-certificate-errors',
            '--headless',
        ]);
        $caps->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $chrome_options);

        $this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'bla', // selenium host
            $caps,
            'bla', // connection timeout
            'bla' // request timeout
        );
```

Вопрос вот в чем: применяются ли те опции, которые мы указываем для `Chrome`, на весь грубо говоря `Chrome` как приложение, или же каждый раз делая `RemoteWebDriver::create`, мы получаем отдельный экземпляр приложения, запущенный именно с такими параметрами? Обратите внимание, что запуск происходит в инкогнито.